# Send .txt file, images, .doc files to the server using IP address and port number

Tags: android, file, ip, client-server, port

I am developing an application in android.My question is how can I send whole .txt file, Images, .doc file to the server using IP address and port number on which my Server connects. In my GUI I have to provide path of user choice. Means user has to choose the path of file that he/she wants to send...Please help me to solve my problem...Thank you...

Comment: Actually I have to send files to the server... I tried this code but its working for only .txt files. Its not working for Images and .doc files...

Comment: http://lakjeewa.blogspot.in/2012/03/simple-android-application-to-send-file.html?showComment=1358334756785#c4288537044906099947